# Remove Windows Boot manager?

Tags: linux, windows, uefi

I have two drives an SSD boot drive and a storage drive. I needed a temporary install of windows so I put it on my storage drive while leaving Linux on my boot drive. When I installed it windows installed the boot code and boot manager onto my SSD(presumably because there was already an EFI partition there) while it put the core OS on my storage drive. I have since formatted my storage drive and removed the data Windows put into my EFI partition yet when I go to my boot menu in my UEFI the Windows boot manager is still an option I can select and when I do so I get an error stating there's a problem preventing Windows from booting. How do I remove the Windows boot code without formatting my SSD and reinstalling Linux?

Note: I did not use grub or the windows boot manager to handle the dual boot I just used my UEFI to select the boot device and had the OSes run in stand alone mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the man page for [efibootmgr](https://github.com/vathpela/efibootmgr-devel) it's pretty straight-forward.  Basically if you run `efibootmgr` with no arguments, it will list the boot entries.  Each one has a 4-digit hex number.  Then run `efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` with the appropriate number to delete that entry.

Comment: after i restart. i comes back. you know why?

Comment: you can delete the entries in `/boot/efi` to make them disappear for good